# Subset based on a range of dates falling within two date variables

Tags: r

I have a data set of ~90,000 rows where individuals can have multiple enrollments in a program. For example;

```
id = c(1,1,3,3,5,5)
entry_date = c('2014-01-01', '2014-12-01', '2000-03-12', '2002-07-09', '2011-11-05','2016-12-01')
exit_date = c('2014-01-02', '2015-02-04', '2001-04-05', '2006-09-11', '2016-09-01', '2017-02-02')
test <- data.frame(id, entry_date, exit_date)
test


id entry_date   exit_date
1  2014-01-01  2014-01-02
1  2014-12-01  2015-02-04
3  2000-03-12  2001-04-05
3  2002-07-09  2006-09-11
5  2011-11-05  2016-09-01
5  2016-12-01  2017-02-02
```

I am attempting to subset anyone whose program duration (`entry_date` and `exit_date`) includes the whole or part of the year 2014. So based on the example data I would like to include the all the following rows;

```
id  entry_date    exit_date
1   2014-01-01   2014-01-02 
1   2014-12-01   2015-02-04
5   2011-11-05   2016-09-01
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, I could think of is extracting year from `entry_date` and `exit_date` and then create a `seq`uence between them using `mapply` and check if "2014" exists in that sequence and select those entries accordingly.

```
test[mapply(function(x, y) 2014 %in% seq(x,y) ,
 as.numeric(format(as.Date(test$entry_date), "%Y")), 
 as.numeric(format(as.Date(test$exit_date), "%Y"))), ]

#  id entry_date  exit_date
#1  1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02
#2  1 2014-12-01 2015-02-04
#5  5 2011-11-05 2016-09-01
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should've split `entry_date` and `exit_date` up into `c(year,month,day)` before you put them in a data frame. But anyway, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>%
  separate(entry_date, c("entry_year","entry_month", "entry_day"), "-") %>%
  separate(exit_date, c("exit_year","exit_month","exit_day"),"-") %>%
  filter(entry_year <= 2014 & exit_year>=2014)
```

This gives:

```
  id entry_year entry_month entry_day exit_year exit_month exit_day
1  1       2014          01        01      2014         01       02
2  1       2014          12        01      2015         02       04
3  5       2011          11        05      2016         09       01
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @RonakShah has provided a very smart solution to solve the problem. But since OP had mentioned about large data I thought to mention that `lubridate` and `data.table` combination can make it faster.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(test)

test[year(ymd(entry_date)) <= 2014 & year(ymd(exit_date)) >= 2014]
#   id entry_date  exit_date
#1:  1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02
#2:  1 2014-12-01 2015-02-04
#3:  5 2011-11-05 2016-09-01
```